# Concept of creating photoalbum in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, webforms

I am creating a web application in Aspnet webform with c# and SQL Server 2008 as backened, I am required to creating of album with specific photos in that Album and want to display all the Album. when user click on the album he/she can view all the images. I am able to do all other concept of fetching from database, here I just want to know the concept/idea of creating Albums with images link to particular album

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Create one table called Album_Master which stores all the details regarding to the album. Then create a second table called Image_Master having all the details regarding to image along with a foreign key to AlbumId to Album_Master table.

In the front end, you can pass the id of album which is clicked by the user in querystring parameter and then you can identify which album has been clicked so display the images of that album.

In the backend, you can create a dropdown list of albums in which the admin wants to upload the image.

Answer (score 1):

Please Check this [plugin](http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/lightview/documentation/usage#usage_groups). There is a option to group images. In your application, list out album names and link it to first image of that album. other images list in a sub div and hide the div via css. all images group by album ID.

example :

```
<div class="gallery">

        
        <div class='gallery-block'>
        <div class="gallery-image">  
          <img src='/images/GalleryImages/635272403629062500alhoty.jpg' alt='' class="GalleryImgGroupItem"/>

 <a href='/images/GalleryImages/635272403629062500alhoty.jpg' 
 class='lightview' 
 data-lightview-group='2'
 data-lightview-title="Facilities" 
 data-lightview-caption=" Group Building">
  <div class="link_overlay icon-search"></div>
 </a>

<a href='/images/GalleryImages/63527244427580078117.jpg' 
 class='lightview' 
 data-lightview-group='2'
 data-lightview-title="Facilities" 
 data-lightview-caption="Polymer Laboratory">
  <div class="link_overlay icon-search"></div>
 </a>

 <a href='/images/GalleryImages/63527244408283203116.jpg' 
 class='lightview' 
 data-lightview-group='2'
 data-lightview-title="Facilities" 
 data-lightview-caption="Polymer Laboratory">
  <div class="link_overlay icon-search"></div>
 </a>  

  </div>
  <div class="gallery-details">
  <h2>Facilities</h2>
  <p></p>
  </div>
  </div>
        
        <div class='gallery-block'>
        <div class="gallery-image">  
          <img src='/images/GalleryImages/63527246491956054626.jpg' alt='' class="GalleryImgGroupItem"/>

  <a href='/images/GalleryImages/63527247704046875028.jpg' 
 class='lightview' 
 data-lightview-group='8'
 data-lightview-title="Our Rich Heritage" 
 data-lightview-caption="desc">
  <div class="link_overlay icon-search"></div>
 </a>

  <a href='/images/GalleryImages/63527247315473632827.jpg' 
 class='lightview' 
 data-lightview-group='8'
 data-lightview-title="Our Rich Heritage" 
 data-lightview-caption=" desc 123">
  <div class="link_overlay icon-search"></div>
   </a> 
  </div>
  <div class="gallery-details">
  <h2>Our Rich Heritage</h2>
  <p></p>
  </div>
  </div>
        
        
        
        </div>
```

i am just replace the values via code.
this may help you.